# Modificar TAG Html dentro de um IFRAME com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de modificar uma tag que está dentro de iframe em minha pagina.

Acho que vai ficar mais claro com o script abaixo:

O tag "streamurl" está dentro do código do iframe.

```html
<iframe id="player_externo" src="https://openload.co/embed/zFec7SV5aFU" width="605" height="400" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
tempo = 5;
tempo = tempo*1000;
setTimeout(function(){
    var download = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('player_externo').src = "https://openload.co/stream/" +download;
 alert(download);
}, tempo);
</script>
```

Comment: É o mesmo domínio?

Comment: Não, estou usando esse código em uma pagina do blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o `contentWindow` ou `contentDocument`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("player_externo");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
var download = y.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
x.src = "https://openload.co/stream/" +download;
alert(download);
```

Comment: Não está modificando amigo, nem dando o ALERT.

Comment: Veja no console se dá algum erro.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at index.html:8

Comment: O elemento existe?

Answer (score -2):

```html
<iframe id="player_externo" src="https://openload.co/embed/zFec7SV5aFU" width="605" height="400" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
tempo = 5;
tempo = tempo*1000;
setTimeout(function(){
    var download = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('player_externo').src = "https://openload.co/stream/" +download;
    alert(download);
}, tempo);
</script>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).